# How to start xterm instance which automatically opens nvi in a "complete" environment with ^Z :suspend capability

Tags: ksh, xterm, vi, nvi

I am having problems starting a `xterm` instance that automatically opens `nvi` in a "complete" environment with job control.

I am referring to `xterm` specifically here and not a VTE skin or something of that sort, but I have observed the same behavior in `xfce4-terminal`.

I have tried things like the following:

```
xterm -e /bin/ksh -l -c "/usr/bin/vi"
xterm -ls -e /bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/vi"
xterm -e "/bin/sh -l -c /usr/bin/vi"
xterm -ls -e "/bin/ksh -l -c /usr/bin/vi"
xterm -e "/usr/bin/vi"
```

`nvi` (the *BSD `vi` implementation I normally use, on a Debian host in this case) opens in many of the above examples.

However the environment and functionality is not "complete" in the sense that I cannot execute `^Z` to background / suspend `vi` and get a shell.

`:suspend` is also not successful, **however** `:sh` *does* open a sub-shell as intended.

I have even tried a wrapper like so:

```
xterm -e /bin/ksh -l -c ~/svi.ksh

$ cat ~/svi.ksh
#!/bin/ksh93 -l
/usr/bin/vi
```

I have noticed that `jobs`, `bg`, and `fg` are all `ksh93` shell built-ins and I cannot seem to find Debian packages for the actual POSIX utilities.

I presume there is something I am missing or maybe I am going about this all wrong.

Does anyone have any insights?

Thanks

Comment: Here's a guess: add the "interactive" option for ksh: `xterm -e /bin/ksh -lic ~/svi.ksh`

Comment: VERY CLOSE!  Thank you for the suggestion. It suspends, but there is no prompt.   I will play with it from here and update.

Comment: Not quite there, but still working on it.  I'll leave this open until I have it sorted.